# Setting non-serializable attribute value into ViewMap: (key: bean, value class: .....)]]

Tags: java, payara

I am facing this problem using Payara 5.194 and java 11. I have deployed the same war on another machine which implement a payer 5.191 and java 1.8.
My problem is related to a login and the information about thew login disappear just after they have been correctly checked.
In other words I have problem in carrying through the application the information about the session. This doesn't happen in older version of payara with an older java. Any solution?

> `your text`

```
<h:form>

            <p:growl showDetail="true" life="5000" >
                <p:autoUpdate/>
            </p:growl>
            
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
                <p:inputText id="username" value="#{users.selected.userid}" required="true" label="username" />

                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
                <p:password id="password" value="#{users.selected.password}" required="true" label="password" />
                
                <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{users.login()}" />
                

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>
```

I tried to update primeface, do the login in the same page without change http session